# r Shiny: renderImage from www

Tags: r, shiny

`renderImage` isn't working when trying to render an image from the internet.  It works when the image is on the local machine.

```
  output$myImage <- renderImage({
    pfad <- "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blue-125.png"
    list(src = pfad,
         contentType = 'image/png',
         width = 400,
         height = 300,
         alt = "This is alternate text")
  }, deleteFile = F)


imageOutput("myImage")
```

Comment: Probably use the `img()` tags directly. See http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/builder.html

Answer (score 9):

You can use `tags$img` directly in the ui or in a reactive context :

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      6,
      tags$img(src = "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blue-125.png")
    ),
    column(
      6,
      uiOutput(outputId = "image")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$image <- renderUI({
    tags$img(src = "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blue-125.png")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```